# Is there a list of all reserved keywords for a namespace?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

When running Code-analysis *[([Roslyn] Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers)* on my solution I get the following warning:

```
Warning CA1716 

Rename namespace CompanyA.Product.Shared.LibraryA so that it no longer conflicts
with the reserved language keyword 'Shared'. 
Using a reserved keyword as the name of a namespace makes it harder for consumers 
in other languages to use the namespace.
```

Where can I find a complete list of reserved keywords for a namespace in C#?

Comment: here https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-keywords-reserved-contextual

Comment: @Coder123 'Shared' keyword is not mentioned in that list at all.

Comment: It seems a bit overzealous as warning. Shared is used by VB.NET programs and if you don't plan to integrate that language in your solution there is no much to worry. There is a ms doc that explain how to change the output from that tool here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019 However, if your objective is to remove all those warnings, you have a lot to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire list, too long to repeat here, is hardcoded in [`IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeywords.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/32d8f1e397439035f0ecb5f61a9e672225f0ecdb/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/Core/ApiDesignGuidelines/IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeywords.cs), in the following variables:

- [`s_caseSensitiveKeywords`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/32d8f1e397439035f0ecb5f61a9e672225f0ecdb/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/Core/ApiDesignGuidelines/IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeywords.cs#L236)
- [`s_caseInsensitiveKeywords`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/32d8f1e397439035f0ecb5f61a9e672225f0ecdb/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/Core/ApiDesignGuidelines/IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeywords.cs#L493)

It contains reserved keywords from C#, VB.NET and C++.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a VB.Net project or is included? Since `Shared` is a
[VB.Net reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/)

Comment: how could a question be answer to another question?

Comment: Maybe OP confused plain C# and VB.Net (which is quite common). Asking for it may give him hint that he may want to look at VB.Net reserved keywords rather than C# ones ;)

Comment: I did tag the question with C# :)